# Scikit Gaussian Process forecasting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, regression, gaussian-process

I’m trying to use the Gaussian Process package from scikit learn to do time series forcasting, but I haven’t found any examples online that show how to do this. After training the process on some data, I would like to submit some partial observations of a time series from a test set to the model and have it return predicted future observations.

Can someone show the code for how to do this for a notional example?

Comment: I'd be happy to help, but I'd need more specifics. Can you please provide the data or link to a notional example consistent/similar to your own problem?

Comment: @TCArlen what I realize actually isn’t that I don’t know how to do the forecasting, but instead I don’t know how to condition the posterior with new observations. As far as a data, it is a (KxN) x D matrix, where K is the number of time series, and N is the length of each time series. D is the number of features. I don’t have any notional data in mind but anything that fits this description would work.